# How to iterate through multiple options of a multiple selects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I know how to iterate through multiple options of one select box:

```
$("#selectId > option").each(function() {
alert(this.text + ' ' + this.value);
});
```

However, how would I iterate through all select boxes of one specific class and then iterate through all its options. I would like to use `$(this)`.

This is what I could make so far, which obviously doesn't work.

```
$('.mappingSelectField').each(function(){
        var selectName = $(this).attr("name");
        var preselectValue = "";
        $(this('> option')).each(function() { // THIS LINE NEEDS TO BE ADJUSTED
            if ($(this).val().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '') == selectName.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '')){
                preselectValue = $(this).val();
            }
        });
        $(this).val(preselectValue);
    });
```

All I want is to pre-select an appropriate option, the one which has the same value as the select box name.

Comment: What you want to achevie?

Comment: I want to compare select name with all select options, so I could pre-select the suggested value. It is for mapping fields purpose.

Comment: `$(this).find('option').each(function () {`

Comment: so the selected option will be the name of the select element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrong selector to find option elements in each select elements iteration.

You have used : `$(this('> option'))`

Which is incorrect. you need to find option elements in current select context `this` using find selector. You need to use:

```
 $(this).find('option').each(function() { //iterate over options in current select
  //rest code.
 });
```

or

```
  $('option',this).each(function() { //iterate over options in current select
  //rest code.
 });
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. That's what I was looking for. Many thanks.

Comment: @OndrejTokar: glad it helps :)